# Selenium: How to get element of hover over element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape delivery dates for items on shopee's shanghai website and I realized that the element only appears when I hover over "Shipping Fee" on each of the item.

I managed to freeze the javascript in the debugger during inspection mode and found that the delivery date element's xpath is '//div[@class="sYwpBA"]'

So what I did so far is use Selenium's ActionChains to hover over the "Shipping Fee" element and then make my driver wait until it finds the delivery date element.

However, it's not working and giving me blank which means my driver still isn't able to find the delivery date element.

Example url: https://shopee.sg/-Bundle-of-2-SOMEBYMI-150ml-AHA-BHA-PHA-30days-Miracle-Toner-150ml-i.93906301.7143079648?ads_keyword=wkdaelpmissisiht&adsid=3545314&campaignid=1926059&position=0

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url = https://shopee.sg/-Bundle-of-2-SOMEBYMI-150ml-AHA-BHA-PHA-30days-Miracle-Toner-150ml-i.93906301.7143079648?ads_keyword=wkdaelpmissisiht&adsid=3545314&campaignid=1926059&position=0
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2) 
    try:
        shipping = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div[@class="shopee-drawer "]')
        hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(shipping)
        hov.perform()
        delivery_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sYwpBA"]')))
    except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
        delivery_date = None

# ROW
row = {
      }

if delivery_date is not None:
    row['Delivery Date'] = delivery_date.text
else:
    row['Delivery Date'] = ""

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('delivery_date.csv', index=False)
```

What can I do to find the delivery date element that's only locatable when I hover over the Shipping Fee element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can you check with the below XPath's 

try:
time.sleep(5)
shipping = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'])[10]/*[name()='path'][starts-with(@d, 'm11 2.5c0 .1 0 .2-.1.3l')])")

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(shipping).perform()

#the below shopee- drawer__contents class is getting displayed after we hover the mouse you can check it in the browser dev tool try debug

delivery_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='shopee- drawer__contents']/div/div/div[2]").get_attribute("innerText")
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
print(delivery_date)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: not sure where you want me to put the code? im little confused to why you have element used in action.move before it's defined in the next line and I can't seem to find any element with "shopee-drawer__contents" as its class

Comment: could you possibly update the code so it's clear? Also, I found that the xpath for the svg and tag is //div[@class="flex items-center deQMhv"]//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path'] to be exact. I found that more elements show up when page loads so "[10]" in your xpath won't work

Comment: shopee-drawer__contents this is getting displayed when you hover the mouse on the SVG element and BTW my XPath not displaying more elements it is displaying exactly desired element I don't know how you are inspecting it