# Python Selenium unable to locate element when it's there?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape product's delivery date data from a bunch of lists of product urls.

I am running the python file on terminal doing multi-processing so ultimately this opens up multiple chrome browsers (like 10 - 15 of them) which slows down my computer quite a bit.

My code basically clicks a block that contains shipping options, which would would show a pop up box that shows estimated delivery time. I have included an example of a product url in the code below.

I noticed that some of my chrome browsers freeze and do not locate the element and click it like I have in my code. I've incorporated refreshing the page in webdriver into my code just in case that will do the trick but it doesn't seem like the frozen browsers are even refreshing.

I don't know why it would do that as I have set the webdriver to wait until the element is clickable. Do I just increase the time in time.sleep() or the seconds in webdriverwait() to resolve this?

```
chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=options)

# Example url
url = "https://shopee.sg/Perfect-Diary-X-Sanrio-MagicStay-Loose-Powder-Weightless-Soft-velvet-Blurring-Face-Powder-With-Cosmetic-Puff-Oil-Control-Smooth-Face-Powder-Waterproof-Applicable-To-Mask-Face-Cinnamoroll-Purin-Gudetama-i.240344695.5946255000?ads_keyword=makeup&adsid=1095331&campaignid=563217&position=1"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="flex flex-column"]//div[@class="shopee-drawer "]'))).click()
    while retries <= 5:
        try:
            shipping_block = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="flex flex-column"]//div[@class="shopee-drawer "]'))).click()
            break
        except TimeoutException:
            driver.refresh()
            retries += 1
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
        delivery_date = None
```

Comment: What is the goal of this code? It's unclear what you want to do. If a user click this block, there are just shipping options. Practically the code just clicks the link and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The element which you desire will get displayed when you hover the mouse, `V` The type of the element is `svg` which you need to handle accordingly.

```
you can take the help of this XPath to hover the mouse
((//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'])/*[name()='path'][starts-with(@d, 'm11 2.5c0 .1 0 .2-.1.3l')])

Getting the text from the popUp you need to check with this XPath
((//div[@class='shopee-drawer__contents']//descendant::div[4]))
```

You can use `get_attribute("innerText")` to get all the values

You can just check it here the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434620/selenium-how-to-get-element-of-hover-over-element/68436142#68436142), I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use headless option in webdriver.ChromeOption() to let the webpage window pop up to observe if the element is clicked or not.

Second, your code is just click the element, it doesn't help you to GET anything. After click and open new window, it should do something like this:

```
items = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'load-done'))
        )
       
for item in items:
  deliver_date= item.get_attribute('text') 
  print(deliver_date)
```